# Bitmap с прозрачным фоном

Tags: android, bitmap, png

Приложение скачивает фотки по сети и сохраняет их на SD. В случае ошибки скачивается изображение-заглушка из ресурсов. Это png с прозрачным фоном:

[image: вот эта заглушка]

В приложении, да и здесь, видны наклонные штрихи. Вот кусок layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view_photo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />`
```

Её сохранение происходит здесь:

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;
try {
    InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(ERROR_DOWNLOAD);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    inputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Как добиться, чтобы картинка устанавливалась с прозрачным фоном?

Answer (score 2):

Тут дело не в том, что как-то скачивается криво, это сама png-шка такая, которую вы используете для заглушки. То есть в таком виде вы ее и скачали, а штрихи - это некая защита авторских прав, чтобы никто творение дизайнера не использовал, кроме него самого. Почистите в paint.net-e или еще где и сохраните заново, с уже прозрачным фоном